# Session Problem with Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, session, authlogic

I'm using Authlogic 2.1.6 for Authorization in Rails 3.0.5 and I have a session cookie problem with AJAX requests.

After a POST or PUT AJAX Call I'm getting a 401 Response and a new session key. After that every call will return a 401 response. Before the POST or PUT call every GET call succeeds.

This doesn't happen in test mode, only in development and production mode.

Does anybody know how to avoid that?

EDIT: I think there is a problem with the forgery protection authenticity key, because after disabling forgery protection everything worked fine.

This is a request header which will produce a 401:

> ```
> Accept:*/*
> Cache-Control:max-age=0
> Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8
> Origin:http://localhost:3000
> Referer:http://localhost:3000/
> User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_6; de-de) AppleWebKit/533.19.4    (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.3 Safari/533.19.4
> X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
> ```

Rails Log entry is the following:

> ```
> Started POST "/users.json" for 127.0.0.1 at Tue Apr 12 10:47:33 +0200 2011
> Processing by UsersController#create as JSON
> Parameters: {"user"=>{"password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "group_id"=>2, "lastname"=>"test1", "prename"=>"test1", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "login"=>"test1"}}
> Rendered text template (0.0ms)
> Completed 401 Unauthorized in 19ms (Views: 0.9ms | ActiveRecord: 3.0ms)
> ```

EDIT2:

Next weird thing: I i send a BASIC AUTH Header instead of a cookie with session ID, I'm not getting a 401, very weird

Comment: have you check if your session is change after your POST or PUT ? We need more information to help you like logs.

Comment: added the log entry and the request header

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A basic error with the 'forgery protection authenticity' is to forget adding the `csrf_meta_tag`

In your layout add it in your header tag. Without it no Ajax request is do with the good token.

If it's not with Ajax use the simple_form helper to generate the token in your form

Comment: I thought i can just send json via ajax and avoid this problem?

Comment: no, the check is do all the time if you do another request than GET if you protect forgery is activate

Comment: So for a "normal" json API this would be too? Sounds very bad to me